# Possible to DRY up the same method in two different controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, dry

I'm have a Rails project which has an api part and the regular one. They have some common methods, for example, I have two controllers like so:

```
class PlacementController < ApplicationSafeController

  def zip
    file = ZipService::ZipGenerator.create_zip
    send_data(file.read, type: 'application/zip')
    File.delete(file.path)
  end
end
```

and

```
class Api::ZipsController < ApiController

  def single_zip
    file = ZipService::ZipGenerator.create_zip
    send_data(file.read, type: 'application/zip')
    File.delete(file.path)   
  end 
end
```

And both my `ApiController` and `ApplicationSafeController` inherit from `ApplicationController`. My question is, what is the best way to clean this up without making the root `ApplicationController` dirty? (by adding a new method there). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You a module/concern to share code. Enclose shareable code in a module, then include that module in the required controllers. It's the Ruby way of doing this thing.

```
module Zippable
  def zip
    file = ZipService::ZipGenerator.create_zip
    send_data(file.read, type: 'application/zip')
    File.delete(file.path)
  end
end  

class PlacementController < ApplicationSafeController

  include Zippable

  #Example Usage
  def show
    zip
  end
end  

class Api::ZipsController < ApiController

  include Zippable
end
```

Comment: I guess my problem is that send_data comes from the ApplicationController. I tried to do something similar, only have yield instead of send_data and then pass send_data through a block but it seemed a bit crazy